# Vue SPA and webpack - minify and mangle index.html

Tags: vue.js, webpack

My Vue projects contains, in the `public` folder, a large `index.html`. Currently it is simply copied to the output folder when I build my project as described [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling).

How can I get webpack to minify it too like it does for all my other files?

Comment: Please, specify which assets exactly. Is there a reason why they aren't in src? This is the most straightforward way to handle them as the rest of app files. IIRC index.html is minified by default.

Comment: `index.html` is minified by default if your project uses Vue CLI.

Comment: I use Vue CLI and `index.html` is not minified... Let me show my config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to my vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config
            .plugin('html')
            .tap(args => {
                if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
                    args[0].minify = {
                        minifyCSS: true,
                        minifyJS: true,
                        minifyURLs: true,
                        removeComments: true,
                        collapseWhitespace: true,
                        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
                    };
                return args;
            })
    },
    ...  // Other configs
}
```

More details [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced)